# APPCRASH on "std::sin" calls

Tags: c++, hyper-v

My dev computer (intel i5, Windows 7 Pro SP1 64bit, Visual Studio 2013 Community). Simple application works as expected

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::cout << "sin: ";
    std::cout << std::sin(15.0) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Then I copy binary file (no matter release or debug) to HyperV (6.3.9600.16384) virtual machine (Windows 2008 SP2 64bit, VC2013 redist installed) and get APPCRASH on "std::sin" call:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: ConsoleApplication4.exe
  Application Version:  0.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp:    565d75d4
  Fault Module Name:    MSVCR120.dll
  Fault Module Version: 12.0.21005.1
  Fault Module Timestamp:   524f83ff
  Exception Code:   c000001d
  Exception Offset: 0000000000098b00
  OS Version:   6.0.6002.2.2.0.16.7
  Locale ID:    1049
  Additional Information 1: 64e8
  Additional Information 2: 160c2ca84e5ab528fe0edddf791bfff4
  Additional Information 3: 3a8a
  Additional Information 4: 8257d6859d8df6782771e833d7d51d3a
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solve the problem

```
#if defined (_WIN64)
   _set_FMA3_enable (0);
#endif
```

See also https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/811093/visual-studio-2013-rtm-c-x64-code-generation-bug-for-avx2-instructions